# Using a vertex as pivot point with multiple vertex selected

Tags: snapping, units

I am try to transition to Blender 2.8 from Maya. Would love to move but running into so show stoppers for me. Am mostly doing modular assets so grids and snapping are essential.

Example. I have a modular wall piece. I need all the vertices on the left and right to be snapped to grid so I can easily snap the modular pieces together later. At current the vertices at the left side are off grid. However I need to keep the interior vertices of the wall looking symmetrical with the right side. The interior vertices won't be on the grid and do not need to be.

In Maya I can select any number of vertices, activate move /rotate / scale, press D, select a vertex, edge or face to use as my pivot, and then if I move the selected vertices with grid snapping on the vertices will all stay in the same relative location compared to each other but the vertex used as pivot, plus any vertices on the same exact axis position, will snap to the grid even if they were off grid to begin with.

I can't replicate this behaviour in Blender.

I can select a vertex, snap the 3D cursor to it and then use that as my pivot, but then when I move my vertices the 3D cursor being used as the pivot is in a fixed position so my vertices move in grid units, but do no actually snap on to the grid.

I know there is a snap to grid command but in this scenario I only want the outside vertices of the selected vertices to snap to grid, so from what I can tell this won't help me as it will snap all of them.

If I were to just selected the outside vertices and snap them I would then have to try and eyeball moving the other internal vertices that I wanted to move with my original snap so would likely not end up with symmetry . I could maintain symmetry by halving the model and mirroring it, but this assumes the center vertices are on grid, which the might not be and might need to not be, and is a lot of steps for a simple task.

I could lessen the severity of this road block by ensuring my outside vertices were on the grid to begin with. But I can't find a way of having the edgeloop or knife tool snap to grid during the process of creating my loops and cuts.

I have found the settings for ensuring the knife tool cuts in a straight line but not how to keep that straight line on grid during the cut. I have also found the tool for straightening vertices so I can easily straighten my edge loop vertices, but again now ensure they on grid to begin with.

I have to make my loop / cut as close as I can get it and then try and use the method above to get the outside vertices on grid, which I am failing to do.

Am I missing or misunderstanding a tool(s)?

Thanks

Comment: Add a screenshot or a .blend file as this is too long and hard to understand.

Comment: ok this looks like more then one question can you divide them to smaller questions? I don't know what you want exactly. I can tell you if you want you could set up a custom grid and use that.

Comment: That's a lot of information, but I dare to guess: try putting your cursor where you want your "wall" to be, use it as pivot and eg press S -> X -> 0. Now all your vertices share the same x value. You can do this along the normals of their combined faces as well, and with a little more fiddling, you can specify your own direction as well. If that isn't the answer, I concur with the 2 comments above. Lukasz-40sth and Mobin.